# Ruby julian seconds

Tags: ruby

I've looked at Time, DateTime, and Date.

What's the easiest way to generate the current number of julian seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'date'

secs_after_midnight = Time.now.to_i % 86400
today = Date.today
puts "Julian seconds : #{today.jd * 86400 + secs_after_midnight}"
puts "Astronomical Julian seconds : #{today.ajd.to_i * 86400 + secs_after_midnight}"
puts "Astronomical Modified Julian seconds: #{today.amjd.to_i * 86400 + secs_after_midnight}"
```

Output

```
Julian seconds : 212172639571
Astronomical Julian seconds : 212172553171
Astronomical Modified Julian seconds: 4812553171
```

Answer (score 1):

[This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) has some algorithms which can calculate the julian seconds. Whether to trust it or not is another matter but I quickly threw together a ruby-ish way from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Gregorian_calendar_from_Unix_time).

```
class Time
  def to_julian
    unix = to_i
    ss = unix % 60
    a = (unix - ss) / 60
    mm = a % 60
    b = (a - mm) / 60
    hh = b % 24
    u = unix - ss - mm * 60 - hh * 3600
    u % 86400 + 2440588
  end
end
```

This will let you do something like

```
Time.now.to_julian
```

if you are so inclined.

Hope it helps

Comment: You can simplify it. `a, ss = unix.divmod(60)` `b, mm = a.divmod(60)`

Comment: @sawa I didn't realise there was a function divmod. Learn something new everyday! XD

Comment: You can do Date.today.jd for a julian day number, or Date.today.ajd  for the astronomical julian day number.

Comment: @steenslag Depends if your using activesupport though.